# ASCII-art milk carton

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

The following is an unfolded milk carton:

```
+-----+-\|/-+-----+-\|/-+-+
|     | / \ |     | / \ | |
+-----+/---\+-----+/---\+-+
|     |     |     |     | |
|     |     |     |     | |
|     |     |     |     | |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-+
 \   / \   / \   / \   /   
  \_/   \_/   \_/   \_/
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) [kolmogorov-complexity](/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) challenge. Your task is to output the above ASCII-art milk carton.

Your output may have any whitespace that does not affect the appearance of the image.

Answer (score 7):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 49 bytes

```
Ｆ⁷Ｂ⁻⁹＆²ι⁻⁷＆⁴ιＰ“↗⎇≦∨⎚üＵP@>⁼γa”Ｃ⁶¦⁰Ｍ⁹→Ｐ^³Ｍ←\|/Ｃ¹²¦⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw1xTwSm/QsM3M6@0WMNSR8Eps6Q8szjVMS9Fw0hHIVNTU0cBImeOImcCltO05vItzSnJLCjKzCvRUIrJQ4YKMTEKCgr6QAaQFa@vBFTsnF9QqWGmo2AA0phflgqy0CooMz2jBNUkqzgdBWOYGiuf1DSQfADUkpgahFmGRmDD/v//r1uWAwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⁷Ｂ⁻⁹＆²ι⁻⁷＆⁴ι
```

Draw the front and what will become the overlap.

```
Ｐ“↗⎇≦∨⎚üＵP@>⁼γa”
```

Draw one of the flaps at the bottom.

```
Ｃ⁶¦⁰
```

Copy the front to the side.

```
Ｍ⁹→Ｐ^³Ｍ←\|/
```

Draw the folds on the side.

```
Ｃ¹²¦⁰
```

Copy to the back and other side.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 133 bytes

```python
for x in b"WwwWB7WQ&ff&6F&!WwwSwtWQ&ff&!&ff&!&ff&!WwwWQdfcfafH6fa".hex().translate(9*"_,|/\+ -").split(","):print((3*x[:-3]+x)[-27:])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3W9PyixQqFDLzFJKUwsvLw53MwwPV0tLUzNzUFIH84PISCF8RQYCUBaakJaclpnmYpSUq6WWkVmho6pUUJeYV5ySWpGpYainF69Tox2gr6Cpp6hUX5GSWaCjpKGlaFRRl5pVoaBhrVURb6RrHaldoRusamVvFakIcA3UTzG0A)

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 137 bytes

`````python
print(b"YWB7YWB7WQ(&6F(&6F&!YSwtYSwtWQ((((&!((((&!((((&!YYYYWQdfcdfcdfcdfca````".hex().translate(9*[*"|/\+ -",5*" ",5*"-"," \_/ ","\n"]))
`````

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3OwuKMvNKNJKUIsOdzEE4PFBDzcwNhNUUI4PLS0AYKAYEaorIZCQQhAempCXDUWICECjpZaRWaGjqlRQl5hXnJJakalhqRWsp1ejHaCvoKumYaikpgEkgW0khJl4fyFOKyVOK1dSEOAjqLpj7AA)

Could probably save a few more bytes allowing nonprintables.

Answer (score 5):

## Vim, <s>100</s> <s>99</s> 97 bytes

```
4i+-----<Esc>a+-+<Esc>yyppO<Esc>4i|     <Esc>a| |<Esc>yyPPkPk8lqqR\|/<Esc>jr\jlr\4hr/klr/qk12l@qGo<Esc>4a \   /<Esc>o<Esc>4a   \_/<Esc>0x­⁡​‎‎
```

Where `<Esc>` is escape key.

[Try it online?](https://tio.run/##HYs9C4AgFAB/yFveLvIqHBrbGpPmB@GWH5A6RIH/3bSbjoO7a1VWyA4YIQW8b4wbKFuwA6ZgaU1rr/0cUtq5ELjMLmRWZyYfMiU/TmFJ6wXKILeL4FdEPgiGp9YP)

This is probably my first vim answer. Any help is welcome in the comments.

-1 byte by changing `3h3xr+` to `a+-+<Esc>`

-2 bytes by changing `qqr\jr/jhr/4lr\khr\kr/hr|q11l@q` to `qqR\|/<Esc>jr\jlr\4hr/klr/qk12l@q`

#### Explanation:

The explanation is separated into 5 smaller sections.

##### 1

```
4i+-----<Esc>a+-+<Esc>­⁡​‎‎­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
4i+-----<Esc>                # ‎⁡insert "+-----" 4 times
             a+-+<Esc>       # ‎⁢put "+-+" in the end of line
```

##### 2

```
yyppO<Esc>4i|     <Esc>a| |<Esc>­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
yy                                # ‎⁡‎⁤copy the entire line (not sure why Y doesn't work for me)
  pp                              # ‎⁢paste 2 times
    O<Esc>                        # ‎⁣make a new line above the current line
          4i|     <Esc>           # ‎⁤insert "|     " 4 times
                       a| |<Esc>  # ‎⁢⁡‎⁢⁤put the "| |" in end of line
```

##### 3

```
yyPPkPk8l­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
yy         # ‎⁡copy the entire line
  PP       # ‎⁢paste two times (above the current line)
    k      # ‎⁣move up
     P     # ‎⁤paste above of the line
      k    # ‎⁢⁡‎⁤⁡move up
       8l  # ‎⁢⁢move right 8 cells
```

##### 4

```
qqR\|/<Esc>jr\jlr\4hr/klr/qk12l@q­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
qq                                 # ‎⁡record in the register q
  R\|/<Esc>                        # ‎⁢replace the actual cell with '\', then the next cell '|', then the next cell '/'.
           jr\                     # ‎⁣move down, replace the actual cell with '\'
              jlr\                 # ‎⁤move down, then right, then replace the actual cell with '\'
                  4h               # ‎⁢⁡move left 4 times
                    r/             # ‎⁢⁢replace the actual cell with '/'
                      klr/         # ‎⁢⁣move up, then right, then replace the actual cell with '/'
                          q        # ‎⁢⁤stop recording
                           k       # ‎⁣⁡move up
                            12l    # ‎⁣⁢move right 12 times
                               @q  # ‎⁣⁣playback register 'q'
```

##### 5

```
Go<Esc>4a \   /<Esc>o<Esc>4a   \_/<Esc>0x­⁡​‎‎­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
G                                               # ‎⁡go to the last line
 o<Esc>                                         # ‎⁢‎⁢⁤⁢make a new line.
        a \   /<Esc>                            # ‎⁣‎⁢⁤⁣insert " \   /" 4 times
                    o<Esc>                      # ‎⁤‎⁢⁤⁤make a new line below the line
                          4a   \_/<Esc>         # ‎⁢⁡insert "   \_/" 4 times
                                       0x       # ‎⁢⁢delete the first character of the line
```

Every section is created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: FYI, the diamond left by Luminespire is for statistics reasons.

Comment: @noodleman, So, should I put the diamond in all sections, or should I remove the diamond?

Comment: Do what you want, it might be better to have the diamond but you probably don't need it more than once per answer.

Comment: Using `Y` instead of `yy` works fine for me; I think you should be fine to mark this as 95 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 65 bytes

```
81ᶴ|+y81ᶴ -y3YJṅ"ᶜgṢṆĊ“"|- \/"y⁻'-4«+JD2ΘṅWfT“" \   /  \_/ "½ddJ”
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCI4MeG2tHwreTgx4ba0IC15M1lK4bmFXCLhtpxn4bmi4bmGxIrigJxcInwtIFxcL1wieeKBuyctNMKrK0pEMs6Y4bmFV2ZU4oCcXCIgXFwgICAvICBcXF8vIFwiwr1kZErigJ0iLCIiLCIiLCIzLjIuMCJd)

**Explanation**:

```
81ᶴ|+y81ᶴ -y3YJṅ"ᶜgṢṆĊ“"|- \/"y⁻'-4«+JD2ΘṅWfT“" \   /  \_/ "½ddJ”­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
81   y81   y                                                       # ‎⁡Base decompress 81 twice with chars ...
   |+     -                                                        # ‎⁢... "|+" and " -" (push "+|+|||+", "- -   -")
            3YJṅ                                                   # ‎⁣Repeat latter three times, join and palindromise
                "ᶜgṢṆĊ“"|- \/"y                                    # ‎⁤Base decompress "ᶜgṢṆĊ“ (9709170788) with chars "|- \/" (push "- /\/-| -/\-- \")
                               ⁻                                   # ‎⁢⁡Split into chunks of length 3
                                '-4«+J                             # ‎⁢⁢Append "-" and 3 spaces to each item, merge lists
                                       2Θṅ                         # ‎⁢⁣Palindromise first two elements
                                      D   WfT“                     # ‎⁢⁤Insert result between two copies of the list, transpose
                                              " \   /  \_/ "       # ‎⁣⁡Halve string, quadruple each half
                                                               J”  # ‎⁣⁢Join with transposed list and format
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 3):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), <s>147</s> 141 bytes

```
/l/\/\///a/|     lb/-----lc/aaaa| |
lf/ d   elg/  d_e lh/a| e d li/b+lj/+ie---dlk/+i-d|e-ld/\\\\le/\\\lkk+-+
hh| |
jj+-+
ccc+iiii-+
ffff
gggg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcw7DsQgDATQPqdwj9BcKNKKgBM@09Fyd3Z4LjyyZU@mWX3uDeJWAQnLDj6IBzOSLFsXX1jRyvnBrPzcWKGNa8qGJ7AjNNdR4VCKZXlkwS300zhGiOGq9bzr/eScc2ii@Mr1yd5/)

I'm not going to explain this one.

-6 bytes thanks to [@Philippos](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72726/philippos)

Comment: Why not [141 bytes](https://tio.run/##Fcw7DsQgDATQPqdwj9BcKNKKgBM@09Fyd3Z4LjyyZU@mWX3uDeJWAQnLDj6IBzOSLFsXX1jRyvnBrPzcWKGNa8qGJ7AjNNdR4VCKZXlkwS300zhGiOGq9bzr/eScc2ii@Mr1yd5/ "/// – Try It Online")

Comment: @Philippos Done!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES11), 143 bytes

A mix of maths and hardcoded XOR patterns.

```javascript
f=(y=9,x)=>~y?` |-+/\\_
`[X=--x%6,x?y<2?x<3|X+~y?X+y-5?X|y?0:6:4:5:["70006","0504","0637"][y-6]?.[x%12-4]^648>>y&2|X==3|x<2:7]+f(y-!x,x||28):""
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY7BCoIwAEDvfUUNDEVna85pw7nfGOhKKNdF9FDBBqNf6AO6eKh7v9PfVEinB493ePdHPxzacXxezhrm75vmvuWbyAS8vFrRzB0MV3W9mzWV5BAaj0ZG2AILUyROht9EhhamQjorEKOMsJRVIEMIURABlCLyA00yoCoLqRJxZbw1hkRtKcnL0i6xk5wnzhSYZSrUvoULExnncB4wAKat137oT0PXxt1w9LUfBJP-X38A)

For comparison, using [RegPack](https://siorki.github.io/regPack.html) gives [170 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYtBCsMgFET3nuLvooh1WwgBDyKYUAg1lChJUBM1V7e/fbMZ3jDLFKb9tVl/iPBszQxjSlxwEmOBQkLAnnMmvCKoL0QRgFP9cxcFUMUPjg0yuRF8XqC1kqfWRiZehdZFioiDRA@BV4kPrcd@dhu14OYuxHReWdW7Y9Eeb2oeu//Yg1rGzLA4u1LvPGWs95tdD2pYa18).

#### Method

We iterate from \$y=8\$ at the top to \$y=0\$ at the bottom, and from \$x=27\$ on the left to \$x=0\$ on the right. We also use \$X=x\bmod 6\$. Note that we have \$X=0\$ when we're at the middle of a bottom notch.

```
  2       1         0
  7654321098765432109876543210 <-- x
8 +-----+-\|/-+-----+-\|/-+-+\n
7 |     | / \ |     | / \ | |\n
6 +-----+/---\+-----+/---\+-+\n
5 |     |     |     |     | |\n
4 |     |     |     |     | |\n
3 |     |     |     |     | |\n
2 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-+\n
1  \   / \   / \   / \   /   \n
0   \_/   \_/   \_/   \_/    \n
  3210543210543210543210543210 <-- X
```

The 8 distinct characters used in the ASCII art are encoded as follows:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  | - + / \ _ \n
```

The following algorithm is used to select the correct character code:

```javascript
x ?                // if this is not the end of line:
  y < 2 ?          //   if this is the bottom part:
    x < 3 |        //     if this is the rightmost part
    X + ~y ?       //     or X - y is not equal to 1:
      X + y - 5 ?  //       if X + y is not equal to 5:
        X | y ?    //         if X != 0 or y != 0:
          0        //           insert a space
        :          //         else:
          6        //           insert "_"
      :            //       else:
        4          //         insert "/"
    :              //     else:
      5            //       insert "\"
  :                //   else:
    [ "70006",     //     these are the XOR patterns
      "0504",      //     to apply for the most
      "0637" ]     //     complicated cuts at the top
    [y - 6]        //     i.e for 6 <= y <= 8
    ?.[x % 12 - 4] //     they are applied modulo 12
    ^              //
    648 >> y & 2 | //     this gives 2 for y in [2, 6, 8]
    X == 3 |       //     standard vertical lines
    x < 2          //     rightmost vertical line
:                  // else:
  7                //   insert a linefeed
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>108</s> <s>105</s> 102 bytes

```
2*$(a+-\|/-)h2*$(b| / \ )| |¶2*$(a+/---\)h3*$(4*b| |¶)4*ah4*$( \   /)¶4*$(  \_/ 
a
+5*-
b
|5* 
h
+-+¶
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sKLUkMy9xwYKlpSVpuhY3s7iMtFQ0ErV1Y2r0dTUzQJykGgV9hRgFzRqFmkPbILL6urq6MZoZxkCOiVYSWELTRCsxwwQoAFSqoKCveWgbmKMQE6-vwJXIpW2qpcuVxFVjqqXAlcGlrat9aNuS4qTkYqi9MPsB)

This is my first time using Retina so this can probably be improved on. This program uses Retina's repetition operator `*` extensively.

I'm hoping to reduce the repeated part of `2*$(a+-\|/-)h2*$(b| / \ )| |¶2*$(a+/---\)h` (the `2*$(a+something)h` bit). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 71 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
"+---
|".B4и¨D1è4ǝ… \ Ćª„\_2úª.ºD"+-\|
| /
+/--".B.º2Ýǝ€¦øJεD¦y2£R'\KJ,
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fSVtXV5erRknPyeTCjkMrXAwPrzA5PvdRwzKFGIUjbYdWPWqYFxNvdHjXoVV6h3a5AFXH1HDVKOhzaevr6gI1AQWNDs8Famhac2jZ4R1e57a6HFpWaXRocZB6jLeXzv///3V18/J1cxKrKgE)

**Explanation:**

[Try it online with step-by-step debug lines.](https://tio.run/##fZNBaxNBFMfPyad47GUPzVobchKkWBbEiCA5L8g0eUlGJzvDzMQ0kkPx4Leol0Iopd5UShGEXcFb6WfoF4kzb3bTjYinbOb99/9@7/9mpWHHHDeb6PXcTMFOEcZSCLng@QSM1e7nCUSdaC9JkvYqSu9P11H5M@oU3w/b0ZE8AW59/dHRUzoZoEJm3SH0wPIZGl/s3V3X1Zl8j9REMONlOPOC4iLUn6Ol4uPkmBkcwUGlgbGWM2AwlGrp9elBebFL8iI3qKkv27Xo2SnwfIQnBPL7LDR6phTmIxIeS2uduV1IEDwPwM4aMvj1qbi8P/2cvemWN8VlePEV11pqQDackhwW3DVwQ2nBFAVR3ARlOleCD5n143LjxMZ2gLmm6n85py7obNVewX57bz9J/pk3MAMLFKKZe8XVpGlAsgnj@Q5dlRehueZK4Da5MdfGP2lEUNJwy2VuXIZUHNVTjWgi79ktz@pYG/sNLsMp02xoUYcNboko5I9XxbqiRz2proVfAcgx/Qk7MdYhygm6E@3fK6/71VtuRj9rsK0ybLeawWN1HJLXAY87w7/wKHoCiluHIevW9nsIFiHEYPQOUcHbOd3O2qv74EZ3KO3efi3OnV2AbQ3QoZomFA3zpakgPOZSt5hbzgTEWexVcXb34wGsL6tlhB2FyOqEAqCcWzWnz4FuhNWMCz9Djos6/ttvabFedovzQZy97Met8qqz2WySJJeJYB@WfwA)

```python
"+---
|"           # Push string "+---\n|"
  .B         # Box it to ["+---","|   "]
    4и       # Repeat it 4 times
      ¨      # Remove the last item
       D     # Duplicate it
        1è   # Pop the copy and get the 0-based 1st item
          4ǝ # Insert it at the 0-based 4th index
… \          # Push string " \ "
    Ć        # Enclose it; append its own head: " \  "
     ª       # Append it to the list
„\_          # Push string "\_"
   2ú        # Pad 2 leading spaces: "  \_"
     ª       # Append it to the list as well
.º           # Mirror each inner string with overlap
D            # Duplicate this list
 "+-\|
| /
+/--"        # Push string "+-\|\n| /\n+/--"
     .B      # Box it to ["+-\|","| / ","+/--"]
       .º    # Mirror each inner string with overlap
         2Ý  # Push list [0,1,2]
           ǝ # Replace the strings at those three indices with this triplet-string
 €¦          # Remove the first character of each inner string
   øJ        # Join the lines in the two lists together
ε            # Map over each line (used as foreach):
 D           #  Duplicate the line
  ¦          #  Remove the first character of the copy
   y         #  Push the current line yet again
    2£       #  Only leave its first two characters
      R      #  Reverse it
       '\K  '# Remove a potential "\" from this string
          J  # Join all three strings on the stack together
           , # Pop and output it with trailing newline
```

Answer (score 2):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 151 bytes

```
s_^_+-----+-\\|/-_
s/.*/&&+-+/
h
p
y_/\\-|+_\\/  |_
p
x
s_..|.._/---\\_gp
x
y_/\\_  _
p
p
p
x
y_/\\_--_
p
s_.*_ \\   /_
s__&&&&_p
sx\\   x  \\_xg
s_ __
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc2xCgMxDAPQ3V/hKcMZxz8kqqUlnY6DUEgh/546t1Tjs4T76@nt/KzV@aD5jjkwwyk96hGlmFvIWy75MgCfRiBUJ5OGdNY6a2XkEmDbdhepuhuX/MV9Sy4OKqCqkU/IkmH6uG1o3jhaXpRc6wc)

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 139

```
$m='-----+';"$("+$m-\|/-"*2)+-+
|$('     | / \ |'*2) |
$("+$m/---\"*2)+-+"
,"$('|     '*4)| |"*3
"+$($m*4)-+
 $(,'\   /'*4)
 $(,' \_/ '*4)"
```

Not very golfed right now, but it's late

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.10.0`, 133 bytes

```perl
$;="+-----";say"$;+-\\|/-"x2,$e="+-+
",'|     | / \ 'x2,$d="| |
","$;+/---\\"x2,$e,("|     "x4,$d)x3,$;x4,$e,' \   /'x4,$/,'  \_/ 'x4
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiJDs9XCIrLS0tLS1cIjtzYXlcIiQ7Ky1cXFxcfC8tXCJ4MiwkZT1cIistK1xuXCIsJ3wgICAgIHwgLyBcXCAneDIsJGQ9XCJ8IHxcblwiLFwiJDsrLy0tLVxcXFxcIngyLCRlLChcInwgICAgIFwieDQsJGQpeDMsJDt4NCwkZSwnIFxcICAgLyd4NCwkLywnICBcXF8vICd4NCIsImFyZ3MiOiItTTUuMTAuMCJ9)